# How to choose where to install applications?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed Ubuntu in my SSD of 120 GB. Now I want to install my software in HDD.

**Is there any way to do it or all my software would install in SSD?**

**What if my SSD storage run out of space?**

Comment: Most application s/w will allow you to select where to store data - if not on the SSD then the HD. 120Gb is in most cases by far enough for most people's purposes.

Comment: Packages are built with specific locations their are installed to. Your greatest control is over where directories are placed (have the directories on the physical drive you want them stored to). Either way as @User24601 suggested, 120GB is plenty (my / partition is only 27GB; I wish I'd allocated 32GB to it, but you'll likely have loads of space on your /)  Some packaging formats let you control where stored, but you can't always select how the package will come (Ubuntu primarily uses *debs* you don't control, *snaps* likewise you don't control; except via directories..)

Answer (score 0):

Linux is a very user friendly operating system. The software management system automatically takes care of the installation. That indeed removes direct control from the user on deciding in which folders software is installed at the time of installation.

In principle, however, you *can* control which system folders are stored on which storage medium. This can be achieved by mounting different volumes (partitions, i.e. "drive letters" in Windows) on specific places in the system folder structure. More granular control is possible with `mount binds`: that newer option allows to mount specific folders on whatever volume elsewhere in the file system.

That way, installation would proceed automatically in the designated folders as before, but the actually installed files could reside on different volumes.

**However, do not bother attempting to do this**

A Linux system with plenty of applications typically does not need more than 20 GB. That is a fraction of your 120 GB SSD. So do not bother and have the system remain fully on the SSD. 1) It makes the system maximally fast 2) System files are rarely written to, so it is good for your SSD, and 3) it is by far the most simple approach.

Instead, consider moving user data to the HDD:

- Leave the data you work on daily  on the SSD for the sake of speed.
- Move large data and archive, e.g. movies, photo's, archived documents, ... to the HDD.

Linux is a very user friendly operating system. You can easily create symbolic links in folders under your home directory that seamlessly bring you to data stored on other volumes (i.e., your HDD). So you keep organizing your data under your home folder like *you* want despite the fact that the data may be residing on another storage volume.